# Outlook: Syncing meetings to a Shared Calendar while in Overlay Mode

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

**Situation**: We have a group shared calendar for the purpose of 'checking out' time slots for a shared conference call dial-in number that our entire group uses and has access to. I happen to have a larger monitor that I can view the two calendars side by side comfortably. This means that (for me), I can click and drag meetings that I've made that use this dial-in into the shared calendar without much work or issue.

[image]

**Problem**: Others have smaller monitors or laptops where the side by side view isn't viable. So they are forced to use the 'overlay mode' for showing multiple calendars. This doesn't leave you with the ability to click and drag events over to the shared calendar.
[image]

**Question**: How can one easily sync selected meetings to the shared calendar in **overlay mode**. I would've thought there'd be an option on a right click. Or maybe even an option to share with a particular calendar when the meeting is being created. But I have not found any answer thus far to this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just control-drag it to the calendar you want to duplicate it in on the left side.

Your WebEx at Tue, Apr 26 9AM will now be copied to the green shared calendar. You should see a duplicate entry in your overlay -- the original and now a green version indicating it is being pulled from the 7623 Dial-In calendar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had tried to just drag it to the folder, but never tried 'CTRL+drag'

Comment: Yeah, I just remember the Control+drag option in Windows Explorer. I figured Outlook might work the same way. Glad it worked for you. Hope I can be of more help in the future!